# Inverting identity plus a rank one matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\alpha\in(0,1)$ and $\hat{x}$ be a unit vector. I would like to find the inverse of
$$
\mathrm{I} - \alpha \hat{x}\hat{x}^\top
$$
Is there a closed-form expression for this?

Comment: Perhaps using the Sherman-Morrison formula? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Comment: That would give (I think) 
$$
\mathrm{I} - \frac{\alpha}{1 + \alpha}\hat{x}\hat{x}^\top
$$

Comment: Actually this is probably correct since the inverse of this matrix, using again the same formula comes out as $\mathrm{I} - \alpha\hat{x}\hat{x}^\top$

Comment: Let $M = I - \alpha xx^T$. Make the Ansatz $M^{-1} = I + \beta xx^T$. Multiplying yields
$$
I = MM^{-1} = I + (-\alpha + \beta - \alpha \beta)xx^T = I + (-\alpha + (1 - \alpha)\beta).
$$